# Collapse HubSection programmatically crashes - WP8 C++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to set the visibility of a HubSection to Collapsed but my when I'm doing it my app crashes with the following error.

```
accountSection->Visibility = Windows::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed; // Executed on the main thread.


Error Message: The parameter is incorrect.
```

Could anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/34aed362-6c8e-43ad-93c3-09cd4517bd34/collapsing-a-hubsection-in-a-hub-with-5-sections-causes-app-to-crash). Instead of setting visibility of the section, give that hub a name a name and use `add(), insert(), remove()`

```
private void hideSection1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HubName.Sections.Remove(section1);
}
```